# Mediator variable causality

Tags: causality, mediation, endogeneity, variable

For my master's thesis I want to study the relationship between structural transformation (IV) and subjective well-being (DV). However, income level (GDP) is correlated to both variables. Higher levels of GDP are associated with higher levels of structural transformation and are therefore correlated, with no strict causality between them. Furthermore, higher levels of GDP lead to higher levels of subjective well-being (causal).

In my research I want to disentangle the income and non-income effects of structural transformation (IV) on subjective well-being (DV). I want to do so using a mediator variable approach using GDP as my mediator variable. The mediator effect (indirect effect) would then be the income effect and the direct effect the non-income effect.

Dependent variable: Subjective well-being
independent variable: structural transformation
Mediator: GDP

The mediator effect of IV>M is thus not causal (whereas (M>DV is), and it is not important for my research goals that they are. I want to disentangle the income effect doing this. Higher levels of the (IV) are associated with higher levels of the mediator variable, which in turn is associated with higher levels of the DV. **Is this estimation of the income effect (indirect effect) statistically valid?**

The goal of my research is to compare the income and non-income effects. The income effect is taken as a given as it is a stylized fact that GDP (M) increases for increasing structural transformation (IV) (and vice versa). The novelty of the analysis is to determine whether non-income effects significantly alter this effect - which in the model is embodied by the direct effect of IV > DV.

I argue assume that the residual of this indirect effect through the mediator variable - the direct effect - is causal.

Correlation/causality thus runs as follows:

M <> IV

M > DV

**Is my model now endogenous to M (GDP)? Or will my model still be valid?**

with economic development = GDP
[image: model]

Kind regards,

Frits

Comment: I strongly suggest that you add a causal graph to your question.

Comment: How can i add this graph? I have it in a word file but can only post internet links here? Sorry I am new to this website.

Comment: You can always post images.

Comment: So the arrow **a** is only from Structural Transformation to Economic Development? Or does it go both ways?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that. Causality of (a) goes both ways.  Causality of (b) and (c) go one way as depicted. What is shown in the graph is the effects I want to estimate using the mediator variable approach.

Comment: Even with **a** bidirectional, if, say, you were to regress DV on IV and M, the coefficient of IV should be the direct cause of IV on DV, because you have conditioned on the backdoor path. But I don't know if you are doing regression analysis or not. Equivalent methods: stratifying your analysis on values of M, backdoor adjustment, and possibly others depending on the situation.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I will do a regression analysis where I want to estimate the indirect effect (ab) and the direct effect (c). So if I understand correctly this model would be able to correctly estimate these two effects? The causality of ab doesnt matter so much for my results, since I assume that the IV and M move roughly together. The causality of c is important, as this is meant to capture the non-income effect of the IV on the DV.